# SQL last status change date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to get the dates of last status changes. Below is an example data table.
In brief I want to query the minimum DATE value of the latest STATUS (ordered by CHANGE_NO) for each PRODUCT_ID. Mentioned values are the ones filled with yellow.

[image]

So far, I could get only the latest dates for each product.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      PRODUCT_ID, CHANGE_NO, STATUS, DATE
      ,MAX(CHANGE_NO) OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID) MAX_CHANGE_NO
    FROM TABLE
    ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID, CHANGE_NO
  ) 
WHERE   MAX_CHANGE_NO = CHANGE_NO
```

Please kindly share the link if there is already a question/answer for a similar case; I've  searched but couldn't find any.

Note: I am using Oracle SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Oracle? Different versions have different capabilities. The best way to find out if you don't know for sure is to run this query: `select * from v$version`.

Comment: below is the output:  Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: One more question - since it seems I interpreted the requirement differently from @vkp. If the status changes from A to B and then back to A, what do you need? The first time status was equal to A (even if in the meantime the status changed to something else, but eventually it changed back to A)? That is what vkp's solution will produce. Or is it that you want the first date of the **most recent** status change to its current value? That is what my solution does.

Comment: @mathguy, regardless from the previous statuses, yes, I want the minimum date for **most recent** status for each product. I will try the codes you all shared on the original dataset now.. Thanks..

Comment: Do you mean, the minimum date for the interval when the status was **continuously** in the "current" status? I think that is what you are trying to say. That would be the interpretation in my solution. For your question, it would help if you changed the status for product_id = 3 and change_no = 2 from G to K, and you would show what the desired result is in that case. Then there could be no confusion.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. I have tried it on the original dataset and it worked. Brilliant!  Thank you and also others for quick replies.  Lastly, can you briefly explain what you have done in this part =>  `max(status) keep (dense_rank last order by change_no) as status`  especially by using _keep_

Comment: That is a standard aggregate function. Oracle documentation for it (with examples): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this with analytic functions (avoiding joins).

```
with
     test_data ( product_id, change_no, status, dt ) as (
       select 1, 1, 'A', date '2016-10-10' from dual union all
       select 1, 2, 'B', date '2016-10-11' from dual union all
       select 1, 3, 'C', date '2016-10-12' from dual union all
       select 1, 4, 'D', date '2016-10-13' from dual union all
       select 2, 1, 'Y', date '2016-02-02' from dual union all
       select 2, 2, 'X', date '2016-02-03' from dual union all
       select 2, 3, 'X', date '2016-02-04' from dual union all
       select 3, 1, 'H', date '2016-06-20' from dual union all
       select 3, 2, 'G', date '2016-06-21' from dual union all
       select 3, 3, 'T', date '2016-06-22' from dual union all
       select 3, 4, 'K', date '2016-06-23' from dual union all
       select 3, 5, 'K', date '2016-06-24' from dual union all
       select 3, 6, 'K', date '2016-06-25' from dual
     )
-- End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins below this line.
select   product_id,
         max(status) keep (dense_rank last order by change_no) as status,
         max(dt) as dt
from     (
           select product_id, change_no, status, dt,
                  case when lead(status) over (partition by product_id 
                                               order by change_no desc)
                            = status then 0 else 1 end as flag
           from   test_data
         )
where    flag = 1
group by product_id
order by product_id    --    if needed
;
```

**Output**

```
PRODUCT_ID  STATUS  DT
----------  ------  ----------
         1  D       13/10/2016
         2  X       03/02/2016
         3  K       23/06/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, CHANGE_NO, STATUS,DATE, MIN(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID,STATUS) as MIN_DATE_OF_LATEST_STATUS
FROM (SELECT PRODUCT_ID, CHANGE_NO, STATUS, DATE
      ,FIRST_VALUE(STATUS) OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY CHANGE_NO DESC) LATEST_STATUS
     FROM TABLE
     ) T
     WHERE STATUS = LATEST_STATUS
              ) T
WHERE DATE = MIN_DATE_OF_LATEST_STATUS
```

- Use the `FIRST_VALUE` window function to get the latest status for each product_id
- Get the `MIN` date for those status rows
- Finally get those rows where min_date = date

If change_no isn't needed in the final result, the query can be simplified to

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, STATUS, MIN(DATE) as MIN_DATE_OF_LATEST_STATUS
FROM (SELECT PRODUCT_ID, CHANGE_NO, STATUS, DATE
      ,FIRST_VALUE(STATUS) OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY CHANGE_NO DESC) LATEST_STATUS
     FROM TABLE
     ) T
WHERE STATUS = LATEST_STATUS
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID, STATUS
```

Comment: Note my question to the OP in a comment under the original post... we need clarification on what is needed if the status changes from A to B and then back to A. Our solutions make different assumptions in that case.